# How can I use the selected prop in a <select> that has a v-model?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

**Problem:**
I have a `<select>` that uses a v-model to save the selected options into an array. The problem is that I can't use the `selected` properties on one of the `<options>` because the v-model ingores that and instead uses the bound JavaScript as it's source of truth.

**What I have tried:**
I tried looking up my problem on StackOverflow and I have found two questions but they didn't really help nor explain why and how. Here are the posts I have looked at:

[using v-model on  makes first option not appear in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842664/using-v-model-on-select-makes-first-option-not-appear-in-select) - I tried this but nothing changed. My `selected` appear as selected but it was disabled.

[Vue v-model with select input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404999/vue-v-model-with-select-input) - the accepted answer wants me to define it in data and set it to null but that doesn't work when you take a quick glance at my code.

**Code:**

```
<select v-model="payload[index]" type="text">
    <option v-if="entry.system_role !== null" selected :value="entry.system_role">
        {{ entry.system_role }}
    </option>
    <option v-for="role in entry.roles" :key="entry.id" :value="role">
        {{ role }}
    </option>
</select>
```

That is the section with the select and as you can see the v-model is an array which I simply can't set to null. `index` is from a higher up v-for that renders the amount of `<select>`.
I tried setting `selected` to `disabled` and `:value="entry.system_role"` to `value=""` and leaving it empty (but I need the value of this option). Is there anything I can do to make it work? Maybe with a computed or method?

Comment: if using v-model there is nothing you can do _in the template_ to set the initial value.  as you said, and from the docs: "v-model will ignore the initial `value`, `checked` or `selected` attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the current bound JavaScript state as the source of truth." you need to set the initial value `payload[index] = entry.system_role` in your script. It will depend on your app, but best would be if you can set it on component creation, maybe in [mounted](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) hook?

Comment: @yoduh
I would use the mounted hook but it doesn't work in this case because I'm fetching data in the fetch() which finishes after mounted(). So I'd need a workaround that works after mounted

Comment: can you set it right after the fetch, wherever that's taking place?  a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) could also be an option.  watch for the fetched data to become populated and then set the initial values in the `payload` array